# Is there a way to open a local excel file using a file URL that has a space in it?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

**Problem:** I am unable to open a local Excel file using a file URL if the directory that the Excel file is in has spaces.

I have a local HTML file that has a link to open a local Excel file.
The files are in the same directory. The link is tied to a callback that uses the JavaScript function `window.open()` to open the Excel file URL, however, pasting the file URL directly into the browser address bar yields the exact same results.

I am not trying to download the Excel file, I want to open the given file in Excel externally in the Excel Windows application. I have Excel installed on my system. I am using a Chromium-based browser in Windows 10.

It works perfectly fine to open a local Excel file **if the directory does not have spaces in it**. The path I am using to do this is:

```
ms-excel:ofe|u|C:/folder_without_spaces/file_name.xlsx
```

However, **if the directory has spaces in it**, it does not work. The path I am using to do this is:

```
ms-excel:ofe|u|C:/folder with spaces/file_name.xlsx
```

I have tried converting the spaces to `%20` and the result is the same. I have tried converting the spaces to `+` and the result is the same.

The error that I get when trying to open the Excel file with a directory that has spaces reads:

> Sorry, we couldn't find C://folder%20with%20spaces/file_name.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

The error is always the same, regardless of if I substitute the space characters or not.

Why does this not work?

Comment: I found using the underscore _ instead of a space worked for me.

Comment: @SolarMike Are you saying that when opening an Excel file in a directory that has a space in it, if you replace the spaces in the file URL with underscores, it works? I tried that just now and it still does not work. If you are suggesting replacing the spaces in the directory path with underscores, that is not an option.

Comment: Are you able to put it in a str variable first?

Comment: Yes. I don't see how that is relevant. Can you explain?

Comment: Maybe the spaces won't be converted to %20 when it's in the variable, idk how that works with js